# Update google cloud storage object meta with .net api failed with forbidden error

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to update the meta data of a existing google cloud storage object, with .net client. However, I always got a Fobidden error. The error message is:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Forbidden [403]
Errors [
    Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

The code I'm using is:

```
    private void UpdateMeta(string key)
    {
        var service = Connect();
        var req = service.Objects.Get(bucketName, key);
        GCSObject readobj = req.Execute();
        readobj.Bucket = bucketName;
        if (readobj.Metadata == null)
        {
            readobj.Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        readobj.Metadata["x-goog-meta-test"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        service.Objects.Patch(readobj, readobj.Bucket, key).Execute();
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

The connect method is:

```
    private StorageService Connect()
    {
        string serviceAccountEmail = "account_id@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = GetGCSCertificate(); // retrive the x509 certificate file
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageReadWrite }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));
        var service = new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "GCS Sample",
        });
        return service;
    }
```

Here is the http request sent by gsutil command. It updated the metadata successfully.

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKETNAME/o/OBJECTNAME?ifMetagenerationMatch=1&ifGenerationMatch=1429863183870000&projection=full&prettyPrint=True&alt=json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 128
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json
User-agent: apitools gsutil/4.11 (win32)
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

{"generation": "1429863183870000", "metageneration": "1", "metadata": {"test": "2015- sdf2", "key2": "4/24/2015 8:12:58 AM"}}
```

And here is the http request sent by c# client. It failed.

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKETNAME/o/OBJECTNAME?ifMetagenerationMatch=2&ifGenerationMatch=1429863183870000&projection=full&prettyPrint=True HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GCS Sample google-api-dotnet-client/1.9.0.26010 (gzip)
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 116
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"generation":1429863183870000,"metadata":{"key2":"4/24/2015 8:23:52 AM","test":"2015- sdf2"},"metageneration":2}
```

I don't see much difference between these two http requests.

---

I figured out the root cause of the forbidden error. It's because I used a wrong scope setting. In Connect method, instead of

```
           Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageReadWrite }
```

we should use

```
           Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine, but I don't see how you are authenticating your requests. If your calls are being made anonymously, accessing private objects will fail. To learn about how to authorize your requests, try https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Also consider Shobhit's answer. Whichever account you're using to read the object must have read permission for that object. It is allowable to make an object publicly accessible, in which case an anonymous user can read it.

Comment: You may refer to the Connect method code to check how I authenticate my request. I've verified the account can retrieve and object, and download it. I can also upload object with the same account.

I also tried updating metadata with gsutil utility, which used oauth authentication. It worked fine.

From the error message, it's suspicious that the problem is related to privilege of my account. Is service account allowed to modify metadata?

Comment: A service account may or may not have permission, depending on what you've set. Whichever account uploaded the object owns it and can modify it. By default, objects are project-private, which means your service account can edit the object's metadata if it's an owner or an editor of the project.

Comment: The service account I used to modify metadata is the one that I used to upload that particular object. So it's supposed to be able to update metadata, right? Are you aware of any other restricts may incur this problem?

Comment: No, the account that uploaded the object owns that object completely and cannot have that permission removed. It should always be able to modify that object.

Comment: I added netwrok sniffer results to my original post. Can you see any problem from the http request sent from my c# client? It's very similar to the gsutil's request.

Comment: My guess would be gsutil and your application are authenticating as different users, or the same user with different scopes.

Comment: It's because the scope setting not correct. I should use DevstorageFullControl.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that your application has Read access to that object? There are 2 types of ACL you can define: the bucket and the object. To read an object, you need read permission for that object. To list objects in a bucket, you need read permission on a bucket.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have read access to the object. The object can be read and downloaded with my account via code.